# How to get the value of every other line in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok so, I need to get the value of every other line in a string. How can I do this? (note: I'm using node.js, so I can use node libraries)

I've looked around quite a bit, but all of the answers require the string being an array, which mine isn't. It is simply a string that looks like this:

```
var str = "hello \nhow \nare \nyou?"
```

My goal is so that every other line on the original string is added to a separate string, like this:

```
var output = "how, you?"
```

Comment: If you've seen array implementations, then just turn the string into an array first? Have you tried writing any code at all yourself yet?

Comment: @CertainPerformance my string had many different characters like quotes and brackets as well, and I wasn't sure how to convert to an array that already has those
Wait I think I might have just thought of a way... if this works sorry for wasting everyones time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.split('\n').map(x => x.trim()).filter((x, index) => index % 2 === 1).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var res = str.split("\n");
```

If you `alert(res[0])` you will get the `"hello "`. If you print the whole `res` you will get the result as below:

```
"hello ,how ,are ,you?"
```

You can use the for loop further to print it separately.